# Реализация MVP паттерна при цикличном обновлении параметров в приложении

Tags: android, шаблоны-проектирования, mvp

Здравствуйте, пишу приложение под андроид. Суть приложения:
1) в окне пользователя отображается определенная информация, 
2) Данная информация обновляется через определенные промежутки времени по таймеру
3) При обновлении отправляется запрос к другому устройству, от которого потом приходит ответ.
4) Ответ обрабатывается и информация на экране андроид устройства обновляется

Хотел бы данное приложение реализовать в соответствии с паттерном MVP, т.е.
View <-> Presenter <-> Model.  Я еще новичок в программировании поэтому хотел бы уточнить свой алгоритм:

Есть основной цикл в котором происходят обновления:

```
class ParameterRepresenter {

   private ParameterInteractor mParInteract;  
   private ParameterView mParView;           


   public ParameterRepresenter(ParameterView parView){
        mParView = parView;

        // Первая итерация через 1 с.
        Timer mNewTimer = new Timer();
        MainTimerTask mMainTimerTask = new MainTimerTask();
        mNewTimer.schedule( mMainTimerTask, 1000 );
   }

  class MainTimerTask extends TimerPresenterTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                   //Здесь будет реализована группа Presenter

                      updateRadioButtonStar()



                  // далее обновление остальных параметров
                      updateTextView1();
                      updateTextView2();
                      ......

                // Следующая итерация через 1 с
                Timer mNewTimer = new Timer();
                MainTimerTask mMainTimerTask = new MainTimerTask();
                mNewTimer.schedule( mMainTimerTask, 1000 );

            }
      });



                   // Разберу подробно только для одного объекта View
                  // Например RadioButtonStar остальные элементы по 
                  // аналогии
                  public void updateRadioButtonStar(){

                      if ( mParInteract.isRadioButtonStarChecked() ){
                            mParView.checkRadioButtonStar();   
                      }
                  }

     }
  }

}
```

Далее реализация группы View:

```
class ParameterView extends AppCompatActivity(){

          @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                  ... //   Здесь какой-то код инициализации

                  // Создаем объект презентера, начинаем обновление 
                  // параметров
                  mParPresenter = new ParameterPresenter(this);
          }

          public void checkRadioButtonStar(){
                 mRadioButtonStar.setEnabled(true);
          }

          public void uncheckRadioButtonStar(){
                  mRadioButtonStar.setEnabled(false);
          }

          ... // Остальные элементы
}
```

Далее группа model:

class ParameterInteractor(){

```
        public boolean isRadioButtonStarChecked(){
                 ... // Здесь происходит запрос, получение ответа
                     // от другого устройства в виде обновленного
                     // параметра и выносится решение
                     // включать radioButtonStar или нет
                return ... 
        }
```

}

Можно ли в данном случае внутренний класс **MainTimerTask** (т.е. непосредственно сам цикл обновления данных) помещать в 
презентаре с точки зрения MVP ? Или его (**MainTimerTask**) лучше поместить в интеракторе ?

Заранее благодарен всем за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут главная проблема в том, что паттерн MVP каждый понимает по своему. В любом случае надо руководствоваться разумной необходимостью.

В вашем случае я бы(субъективное мнение) поместил его в отдельный класс с названием что-то типа ModelController и обновлял бы им Model

ЗЫ А вот это должно быть ошибка

```
class ParameterView(){
```

вангую сюда такое, например

```
class ParameterView extends AppCompatActivity{
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Насчет ошибки вы верно подметили, правильно было объявить **ParameterView** с наследованием. Насчет презентера: вам название **ParameterRepresenter** не нравиться поэтому вы рекомендуете **ModelController** ? Потому как в моем классе  **ParameterRepresenter** делается то же самое, что и вы предлагаете, модель обновляется через посредник **ParameterRepresenter**.

Comment: @foxis Это уже личные предпочтения каждого. Главное правило при выборе имени - что бы из него можно было понять, что данный объект делает.ModelController - контролирует модель - новому человеку в общих чертах будет понятно, что он делает. ParameterRepresenter - репрезентует параметры. Но повторюсь - это все очень субъективно и индивидуально.

Comment: Примерная картина построения MVP для моего случая ясна, Спасибо вам большое за исчерпывающие ответы.

Comment: Контролировать модель (как и view) в MVP может только презентер, как бы кто не понимал этот паттерн. И, вообще, причем тут модель? Здесь не модель обновляется, а View. Изначально все правильно организовано, т.е. данные должен получать презентер из модели (через ParameterInteractor), а методы updateRadioButtonStar, updateTextView1 и т.п. должны быть реализованы во View и в презентере вызываться, как (пример) mParView.updateRadioButtonStar().

Comment: @mit, спасибо большое за ответ.